# FB.api name display without button?

Tags: javascript, facebook, api, sdk

i have this code to dipslay my facebook name, the thing is, it is working with a button but i want it to work when the page loads without calling any function.

the code is

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
function postArticle()
  {
FB.api('/me', function(response) {
  alert('Your name is ' + response.name);
});

}
</script>


<form>
    <input type="button" value="Cook" onclick="postArticle()" />
  </form>
```

Can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

Simply:

```
window.onload = postArticle;
```

Or put below code below the line where you include `all.js` or just before `</body>` tag:

```
<script>
  FB.api('/me', function(response) {
    alert('Your name is ' + response.name);
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Put this code after you have included `js sdk`

```
<script type="text/javascript">

FB.api('/me', function(response) {
  alert('Your name is ' + response.name);
});

</script>
```